# Count dates by year while ignoring duplicates in a separate column

Tags: excel, date, count, duplicates

I am attempting to count the number of occurrences of a specified year within a dataset, but I need  to ignore counts where there are duplicate figures within a separate column.

I have played about with a count unique type formula but get a DIV/0 error if there are blank cells in either column (which there will be) or if dates fall outside the year I am searching for.

The formula I have worked with so far is as below.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IF(YEAR(B19:B41)=2020,1)/COUNTIFS(A19:A41,A19:A41,B19:B41,">"&"2020-1-1",B19:B41,"<"&"2020-12-31"))
```

Dataset below. The answer should return 15, but I would like blank cells and alternative years to be considered within the datasheet.

Column A:

```
EstablishmentID
010/3473
010/1951
010/1951
010/2747
010/3038
010/2747
172/3306
173/3306
004/1055
014/6641
050/6641
031/6641
026/6641
004/1237
007/2904
007/2904
007/2904
007/2904
031/13894
031/13894
006/16416
```

Column B:

```
WithdrawalDate
10/02/2020
16/02/2020
16/02/2020
16/02/2020
16/02/2020
16/02/2020
16/02/2020
16/02/2020
18/02/2020
20/02/2020
20/02/2020
20/02/2020
20/02/2020
20/02/2020
26/02/2020
26/02/2020
26/02/2020
26/02/2020
06/03/2020
06/03/2020
05/03/2020
```

Comment: What version of Excel?  Do you have the `FILTER` function?

Comment: Hi Ron, office 365, so yes i do, but have never used that function before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With O365, you can use:

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(EstablishmentID,YEAR(WithdrawalDate)=2020)))
```

where `EstablishmentID` and `WithdrawalDate` are the named ranges referring to the obvious.

***EDIT:*** If you might be referring to a year that does not exist in `WithdrawalDate`, you can use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISTEXT(UNIQUE(FILTER(EstablishmentID,YEAR(WithdrawalDate)=2020))))
```

Comment: With the small scale sample it works! Thank you. The dataset is huge though so I can only assume the figure is right. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Joe So long as the two arrays are the same size and shape, should be no problem.

Comment: Would I be right in saying that rather than counting the dates then ignoring the duplicates, it searches for all the relevant dates then counts the unique text string

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed you gave a different answer, both work. Thank you

Comment: Hi Ron, Just discovered that this formula returns the value 1 when there are no responses. Any idea why this is and how to stop it?

Comment: @Joe I don't know what you mean by "*when there are no responses*". Please provide sample data that will allow reproduction of your problem. (I tried a few things, but none returned a `1`.

Comment: Let's say you used that dataset to search for dates from 2019. The answer is 0 as there are no dates from 2019. Using that formula, the filter would return a CALC error, and CONUTA would count that as 1. I worked on the formula you recommended and have found a solution however.

Comment: @Joe See edit for formula that will handle the situation where the year you are searching does not exist in `WithdrawalDate`